# XSLT page shows <!Doctype html> in FIREFOX

Tags: html, xml, firefox, xslt

I have made changes in an existing .XSL file in order to make it HTML5 compatible. Everything works fine in all the browsers but in case of **Firefox** , the Doctype tag **!Doctype html** is displayed at the top of the contents.

Here is the code, what I am using as : (Which is working fine for all browsers except firefox)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">      

  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 

  =================Contents of the Page======================
```

And if I try with this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">

  =================Contents of the Page======================
```

getting error as ***Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.***

How to prevent Firefox to display the **!Doctype html** tag ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The `xsl:output` element needs to be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. From how you have presented your question it looks like it is within the `xsl:template` element, which is not allowed.

Comment: yeah Tim C, It was a mistake. I made it as the child of 'xsl:stylesheet' . But still it's not working. Do I need to use combination of both the way? I just don't wanna display the <!Doctype html> tag on the page in case of Firefox.